# Marklogic, Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am working on the MarkLogic Query Console. My XQuery file is not working properly and I am facing this error 
MarkLogic Xquery request error:

> XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Dollar_"

This is the code that I am executing:

```
declare function fill:getA() as node()* { 
  for $projectId in /cf:Project/@Id/string() 
    $s := fill:getS($projectId)    
    $t := fill:getT($projectId)
```

Comment: hmmm...... a sample of the code that is giving you the error would go a long way in allowing others to assist you..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. After you provided the code in the comments, I pasted it into the ticket for you. Before even trying to format it, it is clear that the code is in error.. Variable assignment in xQuery starts with let as in:

```
let $foo := bar
```

not

```
$foo := bar
```

Therefore, you errors start here:

```
 for $projectId in /cf:Project/@Id/string() $sourceCatalogId := fill
 ...
```

That should at leas read:

```
for $projectId in /cf:Project/@Id/string()
  let $sourceCatalogId := fill
  ...
```

Please note the **let** before the dollar sign. This is also what the error is saying to you - "I am not expecting a dollar sign..  - likely because it expects the word let.

I did not check over the rest of the code. This should be enough to point you in the direction of cleaning the code. Also, using an Query-aware editor will help you here as well.

Comment: yes it's working when i kept let before $ symbol. thank you

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as the accepted answer so that other know the solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

Add let variable before $s and $t solve and execute .